# jQuery: if checkboxes and dropdown option is equal, then

Tags: jquery, forms

I have 3 checkboxes with the following jQuery and it works great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $finishBoxes = $('#co1,#co2,#co3');
    $finishBoxes.change(function(){
        // check if all are checked based on if the number of checkboxes total
        // is equal to the number of checkboxes checked
        if ($finishBoxes.length == $finishBoxes.filter(':checked').length) {
            $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else{
            $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    $finishBoxes.ready(function(){
        // check if all are checked based on if the number of checkboxes total
        // is equal to the number of checkboxes checked
        if ($finishBoxes.length == $finishBoxes.filter(':checked').length) {
            $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", false);
        } 
        else{
            $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to add the following select option to the if statement so if all 3 are checked and the checkbox value=1 (yes) then the $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", true);

```
<select name="tcaccept" id="tcaccept"> 
    <option value="0"<?php if($mychecklist->tcaccept==0) echo 'selected' ?>>No</option>
    <option value="1"<?php if($mychecklist->tcaccept==1) echo 'selected' ?>>Yes</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Note:** The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current **document**, so the selector can be omitted.

Comment: The correct use for `.attr()` on special attributes is `.attr("disabled", "disabled")`. In jQuery 1.6+, you can use `.prop("disabled", true)` - [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @Didier G: thanks didier, would i use .attr("disabled", "disabled") and .attr("disabled", "enabled") ??

Comment: If you use jquery 1.6+, it's better to use .prop()

Comment: please check links to the documentation for full explanation on how to use the methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some proper code:

```
if ( ( $finishBoxes.length == $finishBoxes.filter(':checked').length ) && ( $('#tcaccept').val() == '1' )) {

    $('#submit2pd').prop("disabled", false);
    // $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", "");


}else{

    $('#submit2pd').prop("disabled", true);
    //$('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

If you are using jquery 1.6+, it's better to use .prop() for special attributes like *disabled* (or *checked* ...).

---

**Edit** according to the comments:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="col1" /><label for="col1">Checkbox 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="col2" /><label for="col2">Checkbox 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="col3" /><label for="col3">Checkbox 3</label>
    <select id="tcaccept">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" text="Submit" id="SubmitButton" />
</form>
```

To cancel the form submition, simply `return false;`:

```
$('#SubmitButton').click(function(event) {
    var $finishBoxes = $('#co1,#co2,#co3');

    if (!($finishBoxes.length == $finishBoxes.filter(':checked').length && $('#tcaccept').val() == '1' )) {
        alert('Check all the boxes and select "Yes"');
        return false;
    }

    // otherwise the form is submitted
    alert('Form will be submitted');

});
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/WyFkH/) for you to play with.

Comment: how could i incorporate an error message if the user clicked on the disabled button. I have this but because its disabled it wont alert.        $('#submit2pd').click(function() {
  alert('Please complete the Induction Checklist.');
});

Comment: You can't. A disabled form element does not receive user interaction or fires events. Either you disable the button and show message (in a <span> for instance), or you don't disable the button, show the alert if the check fails in the click event handler. (yes it was a typo :o))

Comment: instead of disabling the button, can i alert the user and not submit the form if they have not selected the checkboxes and the yes option? How would i change my code to suit?

Comment: Sure, simply `return false;` will cancel the event. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, im getting there. Another prob though is that im using jquery autosave and that is on the form submit. Therefor im using a button to submit the data to the db. When i use your code it comes up with the alert saying "check all boxes.....", but then once i click the ok button on the alert it submits it anyway. Any thoughts?

Comment: :) done used: window.location.href = "submit2pd.php"; instead of alert('Form will be submitted'); and took the onclick off the button

Comment: Glad you finally got what you were looking after :-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#tcaccept option:selected').val() == "1"
```

Also, just for you information, I don't think you need to call $finishBoxes.ready since you are already in a jquery ready method so the DOM should be prepared. And to remove the code duplication I would export the contents of the change call to an external function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $finishBoxes = $('#co1,#co2,#co3');
    function onchange() {
        // check if all are checked based on if the number of checkboxes total
        // is equal to the number of checkboxes checked
        if ($finishBoxes.length == $finishBoxes.filter(':checked').length) {
            $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else{
            $('#submit2pd').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }
    $finishBoxes.change(onchange);
    // Call once to for the first load
    onchange()
});
```

Comment: thanks: how would i use an operator to include them together in the if statement

Comment: @idanzalz:i thought it would be, just making sure